# Print alphabets from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Lets assume that I have 2 different arrays, One with all  of the alphabets from (A to Z) capitalized. And another array, where I input letters from the alphabets, for example: `{"K","C","L"}`.

I want to extract the specified letters above from the first array.

For example if `secondArr = [K,C,L]` then the output would be `[A, B, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, M, N, O, P, Q, R, S, T, U, V, W, X, Y, Z]`

Here is what I've tried:

```
<script>

    window.onload = run;

    function run() {

      a = [];
      for(i = 65; i <= 90; i++) {
        a[a.length] = String.fromCharCode(i); // A-Z
      }
      b = [];
      for(j = 70; j <= 75; j++) {
        b[b.length] = String.fromCharCode(j); // F-K
      }

      if(a !== b) {
        a - b;
      }

    }

  </script>
```

Comment: What is this **alfabeth**?

Comment: To output it, just do `console.log(a)` and open the console. I'm guessing though, that `a - b` doesn't do what you think it does, seeing as those are arrays

Comment: @evolutionxbox, what is **gonne**, what is **eksempal**, **witoute**? => read it out loud.

Comment: alfabeth = alphabet, gonne = gonna(like, I gonne do something), eksempal = Example and witoute = without, sorry for my english

Comment: @Kaiido It's "example" and "without" i guess. celllaa95 must be facing difficulty with English. Let's just help him correct his spelling instead of pointing it out :)

Comment: No,  it dosent. I want  the letters form "b", to be removed from "a", and then print out "a", so I get a alphabet without the letters from "b".

Comment: she** need to get here english right ;)

Comment: @suzo, sorry it took me 10s to write this comment and 7 minutes to fix the spelling

Comment: Don't use `onload`. Furthermore as you do not access the DOM, there is no reason to delay the execution like that.

Comment: It is a bit difficult to decide which JavaScript features you are allowed to use, as it has several ways to do this quite efficiently. But if this is for homework, are you allowed to use methods like `push`, `indexOf`, `contains`, `filter`, `Set`, or can you only use `for` loops, `if` statements and basic comparison operators?

Comment: In this task I get alowed to use differents methods, like push etc...

Comment: Thank you for correted my post

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is what you need.

```
a = [];
b = [];
c = [];
    for(i = 65; i <= 90; i++) {
        a.push(String.fromCharCode(i)); // A-Z
      }

  for(j = 70; j <= 75; j++) {
        b.push(String.fromCharCode(j)); // F-K
      }

//option 1, you can loop through like this
      for (var k = 0; k < a.length; k++){
        if(b.indexOf(a[k]) == -1 ){
          c.push(a[k]);
        }
      }
      console.log(c);

//option 2, you can use the filter function like so
c = a.filter(function(r){
     return b.indexOf(r) == -1;
   }); 
console.log(c)



//output will be [ 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' ]
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you minde to explain a littel about what is happening here, so i can learn a a littel. I kind off undersand the loops, but what happen in the "if" test?

Comment: The `if(b.indexOf(a[k]) == -1 )` check `a[k]` in the `b` array. It returns the index of `a[k]` in `b` if found or `-1` otherwise. Read more about `indexOf` here [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: me 2, ppl should vote up for this one, cause this is exatly what I needed

Comment: Think I have done it now. Sorry, I am realy new to this communuity

Comment: I am glad it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Just use map and filter like :

```
var input = ["K", "C", "L"];
var output = Array(26).fill(0).map((x, i) => String.fromCharCode(i + 65)).filter(x => input.indexOf(x) == -1);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
a = [];
b = [];
  for(i = 65; i <= 90; i++) {
    a[a.length] = String.fromCharCode(i); // A-Z
  }
  for(j = 70; j <= 75; j++) {
    b[b.length] = String.fromCharCode(j); // F-K
  }
  a = a.filter(function(val) {
      return b.indexOf(val) == -1;
  });
```